# Is there any module that let (selected) users (/roles?) see the Administration pages in read-only mode?

Tags: users

Is there a module out there which lets us assign a permission to a role which lets a user look at the site from the perspective of an Administrator, or better, from within the permissions of any selected other role; in a view-only/read-only mode?

That would be useful to let people explore Drupal on sites with existing setup and content without having to create/clone and maintain example sites for such purposes.

(Click around in any (admin/content management) page related to the given "read-only role" without the ability to make/save changes.)

Comment: Questions about modules to use require the OP first looks for existing modules on drupal.org, and reports here what modules didn't fit the use case being discussed.

Comment: FYI - The only module I know of per May 2015 is for Drupal 8 (I am looking for a D7 tool for this)..: https://www.drupal.org/project/config_readonly - and as for "off topic" (?), I fail to see how this question falls outside of the examples on that page, like "Server administration/deployment" or "Site-building how-tos"

Answer (score 1):

Interesting requirement.

Presumably you could assign the relevant admin permissions to the role, e.g "*access administration pages*", "*administer site configuration*" etc..

After that, you could prevent changing any settings with a `hook_form_alter`, adding the `$form['#validate']` handler to `form_set_error` for non-admin users / users of that role. You could also possibly hide the submit button with a suitable #access check e.g `#access => user_access('special permission');` on the button itself.

e.g

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter
 */
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#validate'][] = 'MODULE_readonly_admin_access';
}

/**
 * Custom validate callback
 */
function MODULE_readonly_admin_access(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (path_is_admin(current_path()) && !user_access('admin write access')) {
    form_set_error(NULL, t('Operating in read-only mode.'));
  }
}
```

It would definitely need a lot of careful testing to ensure no loopholes (e.g services API access, `#limit_validation_errors` cases) - make sure all bases are covered.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the default Drupal core admin content with [admin_views](https://drupal.org/project/admin_views), then manage permissions within the View itself.

You can also clone the pre-provided views and remove 'edit' links etc… and manage permission on access to each view->display using the View access UI.